# How to get access script to work in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Basically, what I want to do is take anything in the filename after the period and move to another column called extension, and if there is no period bring over the text to the extension column

```
SELECT 
    [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].FileName, 
    Right([Filename], Len([Filename])-InStrRev([Filename],".")) AS Extension,
    [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].ComputerName, 
    [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].KB
FROM 
    [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb]
;
```

here is the Data
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the SQL functions [REVERSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180040.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), to replicate the same logic.

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(255) = 'C:\MyFolder\MyFile.csv';

-- Extract file extension.
SELECT
    RIGHT(@FileName, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@FileName)) - 1) AS Ext
;
```

Returns:

```
Ext
----
csv
```

**EDIT**

Here is the technique applied to your sample query:

```
SELECT 
    [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].FileName, 
    RIGHT([Filename], CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([Filename])) - 1) AS Extension, 
    [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].ComputerName, 
    [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].KB
FROM 
    [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb]
;
```

Comment: Is there a SQL Function equivalent to InStrRev Function

Comment: No.  Here's the [full list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of built-in functions.  And these are just the [string functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx).

Comment: Of course, you could [build your own](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx) that acts as wrapper for reverse and charindex.  The trade-off is user functions don't perform as well as native ones.

Comment: Ok, help me out here, the DECLARE @FileName

Comment: I needed a sample value to demonstrate the technique. You can remove the declare statement. Then replace @FileName with your field name.

Comment: Ok, help me out here, the DECLARE @FileName my data is actually is the filename not ':\MyFoler\myfile.csv' my FileName is actually 'MyFile.csv' so, where do I put it in the follolwing script
SELECT
      ComputerName,UserName,FileName,KB
  FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[UserProfile12_7-512-1mb]